Bitcoin accidentally sent to my mycelium wallet. I have seed words and keys. School boy error. Still a noob
thank you for your time in advance.
I’ve gone to send funds to another wallet but I’ve accidentally sent it to my, mycelium wallet by mistake.
Is there any way that can retrieve my coin? I have my seed words and keys to hand.
Thank you.

What is preventing you using your Mycelium wallet to send the received money to the intended recipient?

most likely you have done some spelling mistake on the seed words.
here is the list of 2048 words used as seed words
https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/bip-0039-wordlists.md
use the correct spelling and you are sorted
